# How to find the partial fraction of $\frac{z^2-1}{(z+1) (z+2)}$?

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

I tried the method of

$$\frac{z^2-1}{(z+1) (z+2)}=\frac{A}{(z+1)}+\frac{B}{ (z+2)}$$

but it didn't work. Why is this?

Comment: You didn't try hard enough.

Comment: We have $(z^2 - 1) = (z-1)(z+1)$, so the $(z+1)$ appearing in the numerator and denominator cancel each other.  Maybe partial fractions is overkill to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As both denominator and numerator have the same degree, first divide the polynomials:

$$\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+3z+2}=1-\frac{3z+2}{z^2+3z+1}$$

and now do partial fractions on the second summand above.

Comment: Do I always have to divide if  denominator and numerator have the same degree before finding partial fractions?

Comment: @gbd It is usually a very good idea, and it is always adviced that way in case of integration, say. In this case, though, first cancelling common terms is much better: $$\frac{z^2-1}{(z+1)(z+2)}=\frac{z-1}{z+2}=1-\frac3{z+2}$$

Comment: What if we had $\frac{z^2-1}{(z+2)(z+3)}$ then can partial fractions be found without dividing?

Comment: @MrDi Perhaps so, but the ammount of work is going to be similar to first dividing and getting a rather simple expression...

Comment: @DonAntonio, so it can't be solved using the usual method of  $\frac{z^2-1}{(z+2)(z+3)}=\frac{A}{(z+2)}+\frac{B}{z+3}$?

Comment: @MrDi Of course it can, who said otherwise??

Comment: @DonAntonio, but then we have $\frac{z^2-1}{(z+2)(z+3)}=\frac{1}{(z+3)}-\frac{1}{z+2}$ yet the correct answer  is  $\frac{z^2-1}{(z+2)(z+3)}=1+\frac{3}{(z+2)}-\frac{8}{z+3}$.

Comment: @Mr Please pay attention: to use the *partial fractions* method you **must first** divide the fraction of polynomials **if** the degree of the numerator isn't **less** than the degree of the denominator. Here, both polynomials have degree two so you first must divide the polynomials...

Answer (score 0):

your fraction is improper 
so first $$z^2 - 1 = (z-1)(z+1)$$ then you have
$$\frac{z^2-1}{(z+1)(z+2)}=\frac{z-1}{z+2}$$
and then at last
$$\frac{z-1}{z+2}=1-\frac{3}{z+2}$$